# How to use QgsVertexMarker in a Python plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am trying to display a vertex marker for a QGIS Python plugin I am writing. I am getting a the following error...

`'NameError: global name 'QgsVertexMarker' is not defined'`

```
canv = self.iface.mapCanvas()
canv.setExtent(rect)
marker = QgsVertexMarker(canv)
marker.setCenter(QgsPoint(x,y))
canv.refresh()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to import it from the `qgis.gui` module

```
 from qgis.gui import QgsVertexMarker
```